# Endless Query from a view finally returning result with limit

Tags: sql, postgresql, limit, sql-view

I have to improve the time a SQL View query (which is created from another view, which is create from another view.... yes Satan is not far from here)

So I finally had success on it. On my local database I improve the time from 120 seconds to 30 seconds.

The problem is that on the testing database, when I do:

```
select * from view;
```

The query is endless

If I put a limit on it:

```
select * from view limit 50000;
```

It returns me 49143 results (which suggest that the query gives me a finished number of results)

To lock the problem I increase the limit:

```
select * from view limit 70000;
```

the result is identical: 49143 rows.

About the time response, it's correct, with the limit.

But if I remove the limit, the query is still endless.
If someone can explain me this mystery (I asked to the database architect being me, I was like me, skeptical)

I am on postgresql, I do it with pgadmin.

Comment: have you tried directly on 'psql' command line tool?

Comment: Show us the query plan please as obtained by EXPLAIN for both limited and unlimited query.

Comment: Sadly i can't. The data are personnal on my project and the team leader is not ok with that.
but I can't understand why a limit ends a query that has an end ( 49143 lines) and it doesn't end without it.